# This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace

Tags: angular

My build isnt working and keeps showing thi eror..This is my yml file

stages:

- build

image: node

angular-build:
tags:
- A-runner
stage: build
script:
- npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
- npm link @angular/cli
- ng build Angularjs
artifacts:
paths:
- ./public

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error occurring multiple times.

So these are the steps you need to follow.

1.npm install -g @angular/cli

2.ng new my-app

3.**cd my-app**

4.ng serve --open

I missed the third step and that is why I kept getting this error again and again.

If you want to run the commands ng generate component/service, ng build, ng serve, make sure you are in my-app file, or run cd my-app.